# Is it possible to build a concurrent interprocess message queue using boost?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, queue, message-queue

I am trying to build an application which have multiple processes. These processes need to write concurrently through the same message queue. At the other side, there will be just one process reading that queue.

Is that possible using boost? Or do I have to implement that mutual exclusion?

I took a look at the example source code but it is not working properly for my needs. I don't know if I'm missing something.

This is the code on the client:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main ()
{
   try{
      //Erase previous message queue
      //message_queue::remove("message_queue");

      //Create a message_queue.
      message_queue mq
         (open_or_create               //only create
         ,"message_queue"           //name
         ,100                       //max message number
         ,sizeof(int)               //max message size
         );

      //Send 100 numbers
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
         printf("Sending: %d\n", i);
         usleep(1000000);
         mq.send(&i, sizeof(i), 0);
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And server code:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main ()
{
   try{
      //message_queue::remove("message_queue");

      //Open a message queue.
      message_queue mq
         (open_only      //only create
         ,"message_queue"  //name
         );

      unsigned int priority;
      message_queue::size_type recvd_size;

      //Receive 100 numbers
      for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
         int number;
         mq.receive(&number, sizeof(number), recvd_size, priority);
         if(number != i || recvd_size != sizeof(number))
            return 1;

         cout << number << endl;
      }
   }
   catch(interprocess_exception &ex){
      message_queue::remove("message_queue");
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }
   //message_queue::remove("message_queue");
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If only threads are sharing this queue, why use any interprocess stuff?

Comment: @GManNickG At the other side there will be 1 thread (another process) reading what N threads had posted to the queue. I mean, it doesn't matter the order of messages through the queue, but N threads need to write through that queue. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't really know how to use that lock : /.

Comment: @Pric: Please don't mix threads and process. Threads are contained within a process, but are not the same. It sounds like you have another process reading from this process's queue, and want a multiple-producer single-consumer queue that supports this. The fact that threads are involved within each of these processes would be relatively irrelevant. Is this a correct summary?

Comment: @GManNickG Yes, that's exactly what I need. A multiple-producer single-consumer queue. N threads writing messages and just 1 thread reading from that queue (all threads are threads of the same process). It doesn't matter the order of the messages inside the queue.

Comment: @GManNickG If there is a better way to do what I need when N threads and the thread that read are part of different processes, I could build that way too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given examples for `boost::interprocess::message_queue` work for me. These classes are already thread-safe, so intra-process threads are not a problem.

Here's a full example of a shared message queue. Let me know if you have trouble using it.

`shared_mq.hpp`:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>

// could easily be made a template; make sure T is a POD!
class shared_mq {
public:
  shared_mq(const char* const name,
            const unsigned max_queue_size) :
    shared_mq{ name, max_queue_size, delete_queue(name) }
  {}

  shared_mq(const char* const name) :
    mq_{ boost::interprocess::open_only, name }
  {}

  void send(int i) {
    mq_.send(&i, sizeof(i), 0 /* priority */);
  }

  int receive() {
    int result;
    boost::interprocess::message_queue::size_type recvsize;
    unsigned recvpriority;
    mq_.receive(&result, sizeof(result), recvsize, recvpriority);
    return result;
  }

private:
  struct did_delete_t {};

  did_delete_t delete_queue(const char* const name) {
    boost::interprocess::message_queue::remove(name);
    return did_delete_t{};
  }

  shared_mq(const char* const name,
            const unsigned max_queue_size,
            did_delete_t) :
    mq_ { boost::interprocess::create_only, name, max_queue_size, sizeof(int) }
  {}

  boost::interprocess::message_queue mq_;
};
```

`client.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

#include "shared_mq.hpp"

void send_ints(shared_mq& mq, const unsigned count) {
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 mt{ rd() };
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 10000};
  for (unsigned i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
    mq.send(dist(mt));
  }
}

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Starting client." << std::endl; 
  try {
    std::cout << "Creating queue..." << std::endl;
    constexpr unsigned kQueueSize = 100;
    shared_mq mq{ "my_queue", kQueueSize };

    std::cout << "Sending ints..." << std::endl;
    std::thread t1{ send_ints, std::ref(mq), 25};
    std::thread t2{ send_ints, std::ref(mq), 25};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    mq.send(-1);  // magic sentinel value
  }
  catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Finished client." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

`server.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "shared_mq.hpp"

int main ()
{
  std::cout << "Starting server." << std::endl; 
  try {
    std::cout << "Opening queue..." << std::endl;
    shared_mq mq{ "my_queue" };

    std::cout << "Receiving ints..." << std::endl;
    for (;;) {
      const int x = mq.receive();
      if (x == -1) {
        // magic sentinel value
        break;
      }
      std::cout << "Received: " << x << std::endl;
    }
  }
  catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception& ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::cout << "Finished server." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm :D. I had to modify some things because I couldn't make it to compile (i think this is due the compiler) but it is now working really fine. Thank you very much.